# How to publish a website in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am migrating from Visual Studio 2008 to VS 2017.

In 2008 I had a menu item: `Build -> Publish Website`.

I configured that to put the website on a share on the webserver so I pretty much could use that menu item to deploy to the test server so the users could test.

I cannot find that menu option on 2017.

The functionality seems to be moved to the `Publish Web Site Tool` described here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/377y0s6t.aspx#thepublishwebsiteutility

I can not find how to install this.  I can not find it in the `Visual Studio Installer` utility.

I can find instructions for publishing, but those instructions include creating the project from scratch.  I need to do this on an existing project.

Comment: If you select your website in the solution and go to the build menu don't you see publish WebSiteName?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2017 has these features from the **Build** menu...

[image]

Or, *right-click* your project...

[image]

A wizard will start asking how you want to publish your project. There is ample documentation for this on the web.

Comment: The problem I was having was the menu item you are showing was not there.  The problem was "solved" by opening the project as a website.

Comment: Please mark my answer as the "answer", as your comment contributes to that answer. Thanks

Comment: Sorry Fandango68, I voted you up, but I can't mark it as the answer because the problem was that what you are showing was not showing in my VS.  The solution has to show how to get that item to show.